# Разработка новостного приложения Android (общие принципы)

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-asynctask

Всем добрый день. Объясните мне, пожалуйста:
Моя цель разработать новостное приложение.
У меня есть сервер, на нем БД и всякие таблицы. В одной таблице заголовок новости, Id, дата и cover. В другой более подробная информация по Id.
У клиента `SwipeRefreshLayout`, в нем `RecyclerView`, в нем `CardView`. В `RecyclerView.Adapter` передаю `ArrayList<NewsMain>`, в `NewsMain` хранятся заголовок, Id, ссылка на cover (можно и саму civer), дата. 
Удобно было с `AsyncTask` загружать данные с сервера тем, что передал `ArrayList<NewsMain>`, загрузил фото, уведомил адаптер.
Но `AsyncTask` работает по очереди.
Теперь хочу сделать загрузку с сервера с помощью `Service`, чтобы была многопоточность. И вот оно что:

Можно ли передать `ArrayList<NewsMain>` в сервис, не используя `Parcelable`, так как там есть ограничения по памяти (у меня в `ArrayList<NewsMain>` есть поле `Bitmap`)?

Если передать нельзя (что наверное так), как мне быть?

Предположим, я загружаю cover с сайта, я могу ее загрузить на память устройства, потом в SQLite записать, и потом в том же `AsyncTask` считать и установить?

Какие варианты есть еще, если я не очень хочу использовать SQLite?
Какие классы (инструменты) используются для задачи: загрузить данные текстовые и картинки с сервера, затем обновить UI?

Comment: Сервисы немного не для этого. Вам лучше всего посмотреть в сторону RxJava. Если вы грузите картинки через AsynсTask, то лучше посмотрите на библиотеки Picasso или Glide

Comment: RxJava всего лишь инструмент, но никак не принцип или там паттерн

Answer (score 1):

Тут дело то вот в чем. Вам нужен кэш между UI и сервером, иначе, когда юзер будет листать `RecyclerView` вы постоянно будете дергать сеть, что нерационально и юзер будет в бешенстве.

Стандартный паттерн такой:

1. Запускаете `Service` внутри которого поток/`AsyncTask` дергает сеть и загружает данные и складывает их в SQLite (это и есть ваш кэш)
2. На уровне UI вы разворачиваете `ContentProvider` поверх вашего SQLite и через `CursorLoader` качаете данные из SQLite и отображаете через `RecyclerView`
3. Последний штрих - еще один `Service`, который в фоне через алгоритм LRU потихоньку очищает ваш SQLite от устаревших новостей.